# Matrix of given size with unspecified elements

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I want to generate a Matrix of given size whose elements are not specified

I can use

```
Array[a, {3, 2}]
```

to get

```
{{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2]}}
```

however i would like to have

```
{{a[[1, 1]], a[[1, 2]]}, {a[[2, 1]], a[[2, 2]]}, {a[[3, 1]], a[[3, 2]]}}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this, what is your use case?  It seems that this question might be based on a misunderstanding ...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `Inactive` like this

```
temp = Array[Inactive[Part][a, #1, #2] &, {3, 2}];
```

you can then set an `a` at a later stage and `Activate` that:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
Activate[temp]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using version 10 you can make use of the new [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html) function:

```
expr1 = Array[Indexed[a, {##}] &, {3, 2}]
```

> [image]

If you are on an older version you can [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quiet.html) the error messages and use:

```
expr2 = Quiet @ Array[a[[##]] &, {3, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{a[[1, 1]], a[[1, 2]]}, {a[[2, 1]], a[[2, 2]]}, {a[[3, 1]], a[[3, 2]]}}
> ```

With either expression, if `a` is later assigned a value, or substituted with [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html), the extractions will be made:

```
a = CharacterRange["a", "z"] ~Partition~ 2;
```

Now:

```
expr1

expr2
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}
>
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}
> ```